# Why am I seeing the Text of my Doctrine Query at the Top of my View?

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine-orm, codeigniter-3

[image: Block of Text That appears at the top of the generated view in Chrome.]

I am seeing the text of the query that is generated by doctrine2's query builder at the top of my generated view. (I'm using Chrome)

Does anyone know what might inject this text string into the body of the view? Everything in the view seems to render properly except for this string.

I have checked the code for my view and I am not using any php echo statements, there was another SO post which had an answer that mentioned checking for that. But that does not seem to be the source of my problem.

Comment: provide the code in which query you have included...

Comment: post here the controller function, and the model where you called this statement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what was causing the problem.  As part of the doctrine2 and CodeIgniter 3 integration, I had included the [`EchoSQLLogger`](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#sql-logger-optional) in my `application\libraries\Doctrine.php` file based upon another [guide](https://github.com/kenjis/codeigniter-doctrine).  This dumps sql queries to standard out, which is why I was seeing my query in my web view.

```
<?php
$config->setSQLLogger($logger);
$config->getSQLLogger();
```

> Gets or sets the logger to use for logging all SQL statements executed by 
>   Doctrine. The logger class must implement the Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\SQLLogger > interface. A simple default implementation that logs to the standard output 
>   using echo and var_dump can be found at Doctrine\DBAL\Logging\EchoSQLLogger.